# (YUL) Why does storing values at non-32 multiple memory locations spill over to next location?

Tags: assembly, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

Take this line for example (Yul):

```
mstore(0x24, 0x0443455243)
```

If it was `mstore(0x20, 0x0443455243)`, then the entire value would have been stored at location `0x20`.

However, if `0x24` is used, I'd expect the value to be stored at `0x24`, but **only the first byte is stored at `0x20`, whereas the next 4 bytes spill over and get stored at the end of location `0x40`.**

[image: Debugging in Remix shows what gets stored where]

Why is this so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Data in Memory and Storage is being saved a little bit differently. Though the memory is allocated in **32-byte sized buffer**, there are **no slots** in memory, similar to storage. That's why talking about the end or start of location X is not quite correct, as a location is a position of a single byte. *Remix simply splits the memory representation into blocks for better visual representation.*

By storing a value (*that is <= 32bytes*), you specify the position(*index*), EVM picks a 32byte sized buffer starting from that position and packs the value to the end of that buffer.

- `mstore(0x20, 0x0443455243)` takes the buffer range at indexes `32..63` (in decimals).
- `mstore(0x24, 0x0443455243)` takes the buffer range `36..67`/`0x24..0x43`.

  Your binary (`0x0443455243`) takes 5 bytes *(string length `04`, and the data `43 45 52 43`)*, so when we place them into the `36..67` range, it will occupy the end of that buffer range, and the positions will be: `63,64,65,66,67`.

  - The position `63`(`0x3f`) is in the range end `0x20-0x3f`
  - The positions `64..67`/(`0x40..0x43`) are in the range start `0x40-0x5f`

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, `MSTORE` pops 2 items off the stack: the byte location in memory to write to (top) and the value (2nd). Note the stack elements are always 32 bytes, regardless if you see/write, say, 0x03 or 0x24.

So you are writing `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000443455243` to location 0x24 (technically `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000024`)

That gives the following memory layout (broken down abstractly into 32-byte words):

`0x00`: `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`
`0x20`: `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004`
`0x40`: `0x4345524300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

Two key realizations:

- Memory expands in words, so encroaching even 1 byte into a new word causes 1 extra word memory expansion (memory gas expansion costs are also in words)
- All elements on the stack are 32 bytes, regardless of the shorthand used in Yul or even EVM bytecode directly